# About Shipment Tracking Number

Tags: magento2.3, shipment-tracking

I am Having a question, is the Tracking Number Mandatory, While creating the Shipment in Magento, Will it throw error if we won't give tracking number. Can someone answer, it is so important.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not mandatory.

You can add them if applied shipping carriers provide you with those. They are useful when shipping carriers allow tracking shipment using the tracking numbers.